# Set an object outside the scope of a block with an object inside the block's scope

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

How can I set an object outside the scope of a block with an object inside the block's scope?

My code is currently this, but it doesn't work when I call `NSLog(@"%d", [self publicFeed] count])` for example.

```
- (NSArray *) publicFeed {
    __block NSArray *returns = nil;
    [[APIRequester sharedRequester] getPublicFeedCompletion:^(NSArray *array) {
        returns = array;
    } fail:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
    return returns;
}
```

Comment: Have you used the failure block to check the error and see what's going on?

Comment: I coded the APIRequester class, and there is no error...

Comment: First, methods with `get` at the front mean something very specific in Objective-C/Cocoa and this isn't it;  drop the `get`.  Secondly, your API will be far more pleasant if you create methods that only take one block parameter.   The error handling block in the above code is noise;  it almost assuredly needs state from the completion block and, thus, separating the two just adds complexity.

Comment: I suggest adding an `NSError**` pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem. The blocks are called as you would expect, but this is what happens:

1. Declare `returns` as array.
2. Call `-[APIRequester getPublicFeedCompletion:fail:]`.
3. Method returns `returns` (which is `nil`).
   ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
4. Some time in the future, `returns` is set to `array`.

You have to change your code in some way that makes sure `returns` is set before the method returns.

Comment: What are the options? Make the API call synchronous?

Comment: That'd be one way.   Another would be to have the completion block communicate to whomever cares that the return value changed.

Comment: How could I do that? It would be in the method in the op.